# Why when rearranging this equation (under limit) gives different answer?

Tags: limits

When I try to solve this by using l'hopital rule

$\lim_{x \to 0} \large \frac{(2e)^x-x\ln2-x-1}{xtanx} = k$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \large \frac{\ln(2e)(2e)^x-\ln2-1}{tanx+xsec^2 x} = k$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \large \frac{(\ln2e)^2(2e)^x}{sec^2 x+sec^2 x x+ 2xsec^2 xtanx} = k$

I get
$k=\frac{(ln2+1)^2}{2}$ as the answer

But when I rearrange the equation as

$\large \frac{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(2e)^x-1}{x}-\ln2-1}{\lim_{x \to 0}tanx} = k
$
$\small ,since \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(2e)^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} (2e)^x\ln2e$

$\lim_{x \to 0}\large \frac{(2e)^x\ln2e -\ln2e -1}{tanx} =k, $

$\lim_{x \to 0} \small (2e)^x(\ln2e)^2=k$

And then use l'hopital  to evaluate the limit I get the answer $\small (\ln2e+1)^2 =k$

(The upper one is correct)

Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: How do you justify the rearrangement in the second way? Also your "since..." clause doesn't make sense

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(2e)^x-1}{x}$ is not $(2e)^y\ln(2e)$ (which doesn't make sense), but $\ln(2e)=\ln2+1$.

Comment: @ Gae. S I have corrected it

Comment: Now the problem is just that you cannot commute limit with quotient unless the limit of the denominator is not zero (review the hypothesis of that theorem)

Comment: @vujazzman but the limit at denominator is zero , can you provide a little more detailed answer.

Comment: That's correct, so you cannot commute the limit with the quotient, as you have done here twice. Notice that in the middle here you have $0/0$

Comment: @vujazzman but I have used l'hopital rule to evaluate the limit at condition 0/0

Comment: Not in the second way you haven't. Your first step is to say $k$, the original limit of quotients is equal to the quotient of limits. This is not L'hopital and is invalid since the limit of the denominator is zero

Comment: @vujazzman got it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(2e)^x-x\ln 2-x-1}{x \tan x}$$
$(2e)^x=1+x\ln (2e)+x^2 \ln^2(2e)/2+...$, \tan x=x+x^3/3+..
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {1+x\ln(2e)+x^2\ln^2(2e)/2-x\ln 2-x-1}{x^2+x^4/3}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \ln^2(2e)/2}{x^2+x^4/3}=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 (2e).$$